# Selecting First Tab - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to have my first tab selected when page loads or refreshes. In my code, the content of the first tab shows alright but the tab doesn't show it is selected although its content is showing.

Why is this happening please?

```
<input type="hidden" name="currentTab" value="0"/> 

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">

          <div  class="nav-tabs-custom"  id="tabs">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            @foreach($students as $student)

               <li ><a href="#tab_{{ $student->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$student->name!!}</a></li>
               @endforeach


            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
            @foreach($stduents as $key => $student)

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_{{ $student->id }}">
                 //content
             </div>
            @endforeach     
              </div>    

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#tabs").tabs({active: document.tabTest.currentTab.value});

            $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
                var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-active');
                curTabIndex = curTab.index();
                document.tabTest.currentTab.value = curTabIndex;
            });
})
</script>
```

Comment: tab-pane @AdamKozlowski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jQuery solution for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs').find('li > a:first').click(); // **
})
```

** This will activate the first tab when page loads or refreshes.

If you want to do a quick test, just select any other tab than 1st tab, and execute this line in your browser's console `$('.nav-tabs').find('li > a:first').click();`

Comment: Thank you @pogba for accepting my answer. can I have a Up vote plz?

Answer (score 2):

I see that an `active` class is not being set on page load to the first nav 
list element.
This should set the `active` class to first list element.

```
  @foreach($students as $key => $student)
     <li {{ $key == 0 ? 'class="active"' : '' }}><a href="#tab_{{ $student->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >
        {!!$student->name!!}</a></li>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Man, this is the tab content div itself. He said that the content is being shown properly but the tab is not being shown as selected tab.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay sorry I misread it earlier I have updated my solution now!

Comment: thats ok. Your solution would work either. You may up vote my answer if you want. I would do the same for you :-)